# How to verify this equation $\prod_{j=1}^\infty{1+\exp(i2^{-j}\omega)\over2}={1-\exp(i\omega)\over i\omega}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

This equation comes from A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing, 3rd Ed. page 288.
$$\prod_{j=1}^\infty{1+\exp(i2^{-j}\omega)\over2}={1-\exp(i\omega)\over i\omega}$$

I don't think it is right because when $\omega\to0$, the RHS tends toward $-1$, but the LHS is $1$. I have checked the errata of this book and found nothing. Can anyone tell me if this equation is right? If it is, how to prove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: I get

$$\prod_{j=1}^\infty{1+\exp(i2^{-j}\omega)\over2}=\frac{e^{i \omega}-1}{i \omega}$$

The way to see this is to observe that

$$\frac{1+e^{i \omega/2^j}}{2} = e^{i \omega/2^{j+1}} \cos{\frac{\omega}{2^{j+1}}}$$

The products of the exponential and the cosines may be evaluated separately (assuming they each converge, which they do).  The product of the exponentials is easily shown to be

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} e^{i \omega/2^{j+1}} = e^{i \omega/2} $$

The product of the cosines is a well-known result which follows from

$$\begin{align}\sin{\omega} &= 2 \sin{\frac{\omega}{2}}\cos{\frac{\omega}{2}}\\ &= 2^2 \sin{\frac{\omega}{2^2}}\cos{\frac{\omega}{2}} \cos{\frac{\omega}{2^2}}\\ &= 2^N \sin{\frac{\omega}{2^N}} \prod_{j=1}^{N} \cos{\frac{\omega}{2^{j}}}\end{align}$$

Therefore, in the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \cos{\frac{\omega}{2^{j+1}}} = \frac{\sin{\omega}}{\omega \cos{(\omega/2)}} $$

The net product is then

$$2 e^{i \omega/2} \frac{\sin{(\omega/2)}}{\omega} $$

The result follows.